# Can PySCF generate FCIDUMPs in native MOLPRO format?

Tags: pyscf, molpro, fcidump

I am working on a C++ project that entails reading FCIDUMP files and feeding it into some post-HF calculation. For practical reasons, it is more preferable to stick with the native FCIDUMP format of MolPro, which is that for any listed $[ij\vert kl]$, $i\geq j$, $k\geq l$, and $i\geq k$. As far as my understanding goes, this format allows one to expand the symmetric terms without worrying about clashing with other listed terms. That is, any symmetric term associated with $[ij\vert kl]$ (e.g. $[kl\vert ij]$) is guaranteed to be different from any other term $[i'j'\vert k'l']$ in the list. However, since I have no access for MolPro for now, I can only resort to open source software such as PySCF and Psi4 by calling their FCIDUMP modules(**pyscf.tools.fcidump.from_scf()** for example). But it appears that PySCF's (and Psi4's) FCIDUMP format is not the same MolPro: it only ensures $i\geq j$ and $k\geq l$. **My questions is, is it possible to make PySCF's FCIDUMP output adhere to the native MolPro format?** For sure, one can write a script to make things look the same at the end of the day, but I just want to save the hassle. S

As Dr. Dattani suggests, I shall demonstrate below how they differ. First, here is how the native MolPro format looks like

```
    0.4901530798812482E+00   1   1   1   1
    0.3851086116668512E-15   2   1   1   1
    0.1357703691573445E+00   2   1   2   1
    0.4346387940927313E+00   2   2   1   1
    0.5551115123125783E-16   2   2   2   1
    0.4151840574104080E+00   2   2   2   2
   -0.2794639519798636E-14   3   1   1   1
    0.7348327890437402E-01   3   1   2   1
   -0.2386979502944087E-14   3   1   2   2
    0.8287363963878831E-01   3   1   3   1
    ...
```

Meanwhile, pyscf gives something like this

```
    0.6502249619014371    1    1    1    1
    0.4337148338929643    1    1    2    2
    0.1672559053568855    1    1    3    1
    0.5319758870034718    1    1    3    3
    0.1433508560769139    1    1    4    2
    0.6633892094879649    1    1    4    4
    0.07999383652881964    2    1    2    1
   -0.0193772995125534    2    1    3    2
    0.07934608168082659    2    1    4    1
    0.08312052663122392    2    1    4    3
    0.4337148338929642    2    2    1    1
    0.38578316658518    2    2    2    2
    0.04998352966944281    2    2    3    1
    0.3812871041018909    2    2    3    3
    0.05473143994188186    2    2    4    2
    0.4424236810822116    2    2    4    4
```

Notice that terms with $i<k$ are listed in the second example, which is not the case in the first. The PySCF code used is also given below

````
from pyscf import gto,scf
from pyscf.tools import fcidump

mol = gto.M(atom = 'C 0 0 0; C 0 0 1.2', basis = '6-31g', symmetry=True)

# RHF
rhf_obj = scf.RHF(mol)
rhf_obj.kernel()

fcidump.from_scf(rhf_obj,filename="c2_rhf.fcidump",molpro_orbsym=fcidump.MOLPRO_ORBSYM)
```
````

Comment: +1 but can you please send us an example of a PySCF calculation that does not work with an FCIDUMP file that is created by Molpro?

Comment: @NikeDattani Thank you for you reply Dr. Dattani. I have polished the question with more examples. In fact, it is the output format of pyscf.tools.fcidump module that concerns me. But have made it more clearly written.

Comment: Thank you Izzy! Can you please try to enforce D2h symmetry for this C2 molecule in PySCF? Molpro will automatically be using D2h symmetry for a C2 molecule, so there will be fewer numbers listed in the FCIDUMP.

Comment: In principle this should be rather straightforward, since Peter Knowles, the person who developed the FCIDUMP format and is also a lead author of Molpro, has released an open source C++ library for handling FCIDUMP files. The library is available at https://bitbucket.org/pjknowles/fcidump/src/master/ Perhaps PySCF and Psi4 would be willing to switch to using Knowles' implementation?